# Docker container disappeared and job too slow

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a multi-threaded data-processing job that completes in around 5 hours (same code) on an EC2 instance. But when it is run on a docker container (I configured it to have  7 GB of RAM before creating the container), the job runs slowly in docker container for about 12+ hours and then docker container disappeared. How can we fix this ? Why should the job be very slow in the docker container? CPU processing was very very slow in the docker container, not just the network I/O. Network I/O being slow is fine. But I 'm wondering what could be the cause for the CPU processing being very slow compared to EC2 instance. Also where can I find the detailed trace of what happened in the host operating system to cause the docker container to die.

```
**docker logs <container_id>**
19-Feb-2019 22:49:42.098 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Feb-2019 22:49:42.105 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
19-Feb-2019 22:49:42.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 27468 ms
19-Feb-2019 22:55:12.122 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/logging]
19-Feb-2019 22:55:12.154 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/logging] has finished in [32] ms
searchResourcePath=[null], isSearchResourceAvailable=[false]
knowledgeCommonResourcePath=[null], isKnowledgeCommonResourceAvailable=[false]
Load language resource fail...
blah blah blah some application log
bash: line 1:    10 Killed                  /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
Error in Tomcat run: 137 ... failed!
```

Up on doing dmesg -T |  grep docker, this is what I see. What is 500 dockerd? -500 docker-proxy?  How to interpret what is here under?

```
[Tue Feb 19 14:49:04 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered blocking state
[Tue Feb 19 14:49:04 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered forwarding state
[Tue Feb 19 14:49:04 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered disabled state
[Tue Feb 19 14:49:07 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered blocking state
[Tue Feb 19 14:49:07 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered forwarding state
**[Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [10510]     0 10510   197835    12301     111        0          -500 dockerd
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [11241]     0 11241    84733     5434      53        0             0 docker
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [11297]     0 11297    29279      292      18        0          -500 docker-proxy**
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:30 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered disabled state
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:30 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered disabled state
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:30 2019] docker0: port 1(vethc30f313) entered disabled state
```

At 04:09:23, From above, it shows 500 dockerd etc and from below, at 04:09:24 it does Kill 11369 Java process score etc. What does it mean? Did it not kill docker process? It killed Java process running inside the docker container?

demsg -T | grep java
Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [ 3281]   503  3281   654479    38824     145        0             0 java
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [11369]     0 11369  3253416  1757772    4385        0             0 java
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:24 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 11369 (java) score 914 or sacrifice child
[Wed Feb 20 04:09:24 2019] Killed process 11369 (java) total-vm:13013664kB, anon-rss:7031088kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Comment: `Killed` likely means you hit an out of memory error and the kernel (outside of docker) killed the process.

Comment: The reason that the container "disappears" is because a container runs what ever you tell it in the command and then kills itself - by definition. please explain what is the error that you show here (in the question you asked about why its slow and did not mention an error)

Comment: @BMitch Thanks for the response. From the host side, where can I see the detailed trace of what exactly happened.

Comment: @Vineel you can try the kernel/OS logs in /var/log.

Comment: "By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows. [...] By default, each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles is unlimited"

As BMitch and NotSoShabby said you should investigate the error. Access the logs and see what you can find.

Comment: @BMitch do my logs confirm the same? It shows 500 for dockerd and kills Java process shows  OOM for Java process (not the docker process). Actually a Java process is running inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR you need to increase the memory on your VM/host, or reduce the memory usage of your application.

The OS is killing Java which is running inside the container because the host ran out of memory. When the process inside the container dies, the container itself goes into an exited state. You can see these non-running containers with `docker ps -a`.

By default, docker does not limit the CPU or memory of a container. You can add these limits on containers, and if your container exceeds the container memory limits, docker will kill the container. That result will be visible with an OOM status when you inspect the stopped container.

The reason you see ether -500 lines setup on the docker processes is to prevent the OS from killing docker itself when the host runs out of memory. Instead, the process inside the container gets killed, and you can have a restart policy configured in docker to restart that container.

You can read more about memory limits, and configuring the OOM score for container processes at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Are you sure by-default docker doesn't limit the memory that the container can use? On my MAC GUI of docker, I can see its set of max of 2 GB by default.

Comment: @Vineel That's the size of the VM that docker runs inside, similar to picking a VM size in AWS. The docker engine runs inside of that VM and can use all resources allocated to it. On new versions of Docker for Mac, xhyve + linuxkit are used to run docker.

Comment: when we enable docker restart, if we have some files that we are writing, will they be retained?

Comment: @Vineel If the container itself it configured to restart, then any files in volumes or in the container filesystem itself will be there. Anything in a tmpfs would be lost. If you restart with an orchestrator like Swarm Mode, then only the data stored in a volume would be retained.